# Pinia Store is working in dev but not in build version

Tags: vue.js, state, vuejs3, pinia

I have the following problem and no idea how to fix it.

I am using a pinia store with vue and it works fine in dev mode but if I build it, I get undefined.

This is how it looks like:

**main.js:**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from './App.vue'

import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';

const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)
app.use(VueAxios, axios)
app.use(VueCookies);
app.provide('axios', app.config.globalProperties.axios)
app.mount('#app')

import "/src/assets/styles.css";
```

**Template:**

```
<script setup>
import FormState1 from "@/components/FormStateStep1.vue";
import FormState2 from "@/components/FormStateStep2.vue";
import FormState3 from "@/components/FormStateStep3.vue";
import FormStateFinish from "@/components/FormStateStepFinish.vue";

import { useDataStore } from "../stores/stateData.js";
import { useInputDataStore } from "../stores/inputData.js";

const dataStore = useDataStore();
const inputDataStore = useInputDataStore();

</script>

<template>
  <div class="grid-container bewerbungsform direkt">
    <div ref="formular-top" style="height: 50px; position: absolute; top: -50px; pointer-events: none"></div>
    <div v-if="dataStore.formState == 0">
      <FormState1 />
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="dataStore.formState === 1">
      <FormState2 />
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="dataStore.formState === 2">
      <FormState3 />
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="dataStore.formState === 3">
      <FormStateFinish />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FormView",
  components: {
    FormState1,
    FormState2,
    FormState3,
    FormStateFinish,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  beforeCreate() {
    // check how old the data is and reset if more than 1 hour
    if (this.dataStore.getAge >= 1) {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.dataStore.$reset();
      this.inputDataStore.$reset();
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.dataStore.updateTimestamp();
  },

  methods: {
    scrollToTop() {
      // scroll to element with id "app"
      this.$refs["formular-top"].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If I run the build version I get the following errors:

- this.dataStore is undefined
- this.inputDataStore is undefined

I expected it working like the dev version.

Comment: Have you considered putting all your component code in script setup syntax? Your approach seems problematic and difficult to follow because of the mixing of Vue APIs. I wouldnt be surprised if it just worked if you changed it.

Comment: Or you can use the options API with this approach: https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/options-api.html#usage-without-setup

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [RoboKozo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387285/robokozo) your answer helps to fix it.

This Template Syntax works in build code:

```
<template>
  <div class="grid-container bewerbungsform direkt">
    <div
      ref="formular-top"
      style="height: 50px; position: absolute; top: -50px; pointer-events: none"
    ></div>
    <div v-if="dataStore.formState == 0">
      <FormState1 />
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="dataStore.formState === 1">
      <FormState2 />
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="dataStore.formState === 2">
      <FormState3 />
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="dataStore.formState === 3">
      <FormStateFinish />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FormState1 from "@/components/FormStateStep1.vue";
import FormState2 from "@/components/FormStateStep2.vue";
import FormState3 from "@/components/FormStateStep3.vue";
import FormStateFinish from "@/components/FormStateStepFinish.vue";

import { useDataStore } from "../stores/stateData.js";
import { useInputDataStore } from "../stores/inputData.js";

export default {
  name: "FormView",

  setup() {
    const dataStore = useDataStore();
    const inputDataStore = useInputDataStore();

    return {
      dataStore,
      inputDataStore,
    };
  },

  components: {
    FormState1,
    FormState2,
    FormState3,
    FormStateFinish,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  beforeCreate() {
    // check how old the data is and reset if more than 1 hour
    if (this.dataStore.getAge >= 1 || this.dataStore.getReset === true) {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.dataStore.$reset();
      this.inputDataStore.$reset();
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.dataStore.updateTimestamp();
  },

  methods: {
    scrollToTop() {
      // scroll to element with id "app"
      this.$refs["formular-top"].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```